# How I connect JdbcSinkConnector with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I got error when I try to connect jdbc, My propose is I want to create CDC Postgres to Postgres with Kafka

this is my config of I try to connect
[Kafka error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPBkr.png)

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-sink-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5434/postgres",
    "connection.database": "postgres",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "xxxxx",
    "connection.schema": "inventory",
    "topics": "main.inventory.customers",
    "transforms": "unwrap",                                                  
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "auto.create": "true", 
    "auto.evolve": "true",                                                
    "insert.mode": "upsert",                                               
    "pk.fields": "id",                                                       
    "pk.mode": "record_value" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Now, I can fix it by preparing the sink table as the main table. I don't know how but when I prepared tables before connecting on the connector it worked maybe auto.create I miss understanding it